# String loop inside for loop

Tags: java, loops

I'm trying to make a frame with plenty of rectangles inside a rectangle. I want those who are inside to be different colors, so I've tried to make a for loop with different coordinates and color. But my String loop that I found searching doesn't work very well inside the loop. It just prints all coordinates with one color( like:

```
g2.setColor(Color.CYAN);g.drawRect(247, 197, 50, 50);
g2.setColor(Color.CYAN);g.drawRect(244, 194, 49, 49);
g2.setColor(Color.CYAN);g.drawRect(241, 191, 48, 48);
g2.setColor(Color.RED);g.drawRect(247, 197, 50, 50);
g2.setColor(Color.RED);g.drawRect(244, 194, 49, 49);
g2.setColor(Color.RED);g.drawRect(241, 191, 48, 48);
```

)
, then the next color with the coordinates etc. but i want it in a single row ( like:

```
g2.setColor(Color.CYAN);g.drawRect(247, 197, 50, 50);
g2.setColor(Color.RED);g.drawRect(244, 194, 49, 49);
g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);g.drawRect(241, 191, 48, 48);
g2.setColor(Color.GREEN);g.drawRect(238, 188, 47, 47);
g2.setColor(Color.PINK);g.drawRect(235, 185, 46, 46);
g2.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);g.drawRect(232, 182, 45, 45);
```

I have created this code, but I just doesn't understand whats wrong?!

```
 package src;

 import java.awt.Color;
 import java.awt.Graphics;
 import java.awt.Graphics2D;
 import javax.swing.JFrame;
 import javax.swing.JPanel;


  @SuppressWarnings("serial")
  public class Nr1 extends JPanel {

JFrame frame = new JFrame();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

new Nr1();


}
public Nr1(){

    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setBackground(Color.gray);
    frame.setForeground(Color.pink);

    frame.setSize(1845, 800);
    frame.setResizable(false);

       int i;   
       int y = 250;
       int z = 200;
    String [] names ={"CYAN", "PINK", "MAGENTA", "YELLOW", "GREEN", "BLUE", "RED"};
    for( String name : names ) {
       for (i=50;i > 0;i--){ 

           y = y -3;
           z = z -3;

           System.out.print("g2.setColor(Color." + name + ");");
           System.out.print("g.drawRect(" + y + ", " + z + ", " + i +", " + i + ");\n");
        }}

 java.awt.Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
        contentPane.add(new RörandeMojäng3());
}
 }
  @SuppressWarnings("serial")
  class RörandeMojäng3 extends JPanel {

public void paint (Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;


    g2.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
    g.drawRect(200, 200, 50, 50);
    g2.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.drawRect(201, 201, 48, 48);



 }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Code which is printed via System.out.print will not be executed.

Use a color array instead of the string array.

Answer (score 0):

Store the colors in an array of type `Color` as follows,
`Color[] colors = { Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.BLACK };`

`System.out.print()` **writes to the console** and not into the code.

Comment: I want to write it into the console, because I'm going to copy and paste it if it works good, but it doesn't yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to switch the lines

```
for( String name : names ) {
for (i=50;i > 0;i--){
```

to

```
for (i=50;i > 0;i--){  
for( String name : names ) {
```

Comment: Thank you! That got it go in order

    - g2.setColor(Color.CYAN);g.drawRect(250, 200, 50, 50);
    - g2.setColor(Color.PINK);g.drawRect(250, 200, 50, 50);
    - g2.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);g.drawRect(250, 200, 50, 50);
    - g2.setColor(Color.YELLOW);g.drawRect(250, 200, 50, 50);
    - g2.setColor(Color.GREEN);g.drawRect(250, 200, 50, 50);
The problem now is that all colors have all coordinates, I want it